# How to get script run to the end even when closing connection?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible for script to run on its own on sql server when connection closes without sql server agent?

I'd like to start for example long insert script from ETL and have it run through the night without logging into remote server and running that there.

SQL Server Agent is doing the work at the moment but it would be nice to dynamically adjust those scripts in ETL software without having to change job steps in agent.

Hope there is just some obvious trick which hasn't crossed my mind :)

Comment: Why *don't* you do that in your ETL tool then? Why not just add another SQL Task in SSIS for example? If you want to run the taks based on a condition, you can define it in the control flow connection

Comment: Yep I could use conditions for different tasks but that doesn't help me to get to the goal which is to close for example SSIS while the script is still running.

Comment: The last comment makes no sense. If you want to close the ETL script - just don't do anything. If you want to do something when the script finishes, just add another step. If you want something to happen when the ETL finishes, no matter what, add an event handler. You *really* have to explain what you want in order to get an answer

Comment: "Is it possible for script to run on its own on sql server when connection closes !without sql server agent!? " I'd like to type script on wherever, send that on sql server to run on its own without sql agent. Sorry for not being precise enough. Hope this helps.

Comment: That's what's at the top of the question. The rest and the comments ask something *completely* different. What does the agent have to do with connections anyway? You could execute the ETL job from the command line, eg with dtexec and it should behave the same

Comment: This sounds like a case of the XY problem. You have a problem with X, think the solution is Y so you ask about Y. What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve?